# Create a plot which highlight the weeks for which records exists by group for any of the day in table

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table, ggvis

Let's say that the data.table `dt` looks like this:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(grp = c("01", "01","01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "02", "02", "02",
                     "03", "03", "03",
                     "04", "04", "04", "04"),
             date = c("2012-04-18", "2012-04-19","2012-04-30", "2012-05-10", "2012-06-23", "2012-06-25", 
                      "2012-07-05", "2012-07-06", 
                      "2012-04-07", "2012-04-19", "2012-04-05",
                      "2012-04-04", "2012-04-22", "2012-04-25", 
                      "2012-05-19", "2012-06-05", "2012-06-26", "2012-06-27"))



> dt
    grp       date
 1:  01 2012-04-18
 2:  01 2012-04-19
 3:  01 2012-04-30
 4:  01 2012-05-10
 5:  01 2012-06-23
 6:  01 2012-06-25
 7:  01 2012-07-05
 8:  01 2012-07-06
 9:  02 2012-04-07
10:  02 2012-04-19
11:  02 2012-04-05
12:  03 2012-04-04
13:  03 2012-04-22
14:  03 2012-04-25
15:  04 2012-05-19
16:  04 2012-06-05
17:  04 2012-06-26
18:  04 2012-06-27
```

I want to create a plot for each of the groups `grp` highlighting the weeks for which I have records. I wanted a chart something like this:

[image: Bad paint skills]

So I  tried the following but it is only putting a `|` on the days i have records

```
ggplot(dt) +
   aes(y = grp, x = as.Date(date)) +
   geom_segment(aes(yend = grp, 
                    xend = as.Date(date), 
                    color = grp), 
                size = 6,
                show.legend = FALSE) +
   geom_text(aes(label = grp), 
             nudge_x = 3,
             size = 5) +
   scale_x_date('Date', date_breaks = '7 days', expand = c(0, 2)) +
   scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set3') +
   theme_bw() +
   theme(axis.line.y = element_blank(),
         axis.text.y = element_blank(),
         axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
```

Right now my plot is looking like this:[image]
How can I improve my plot to the desired one?

Comment: so each line in plot represents separate group `grp`.

Comment: My date break is 7 days, i.e, a week, so if for a particular week I have records for any day , I want to highlight the whole week and not just that day.

Comment: are you willing to have a plot such as this https://ibb.co/dQedtF ?

Comment: @agerom I am Ok to have a line which joins the end of the weeks say from sunday to saturday in which a date falls, But not as per the chart which was there in the link. it was like joining two plotted points.

Comment: I see what you mean ... Let me ponder and get back to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work for you? For each date in `dt` it grabs the start of the week and the end of the week that it falls in. Then it plots a line segment for each start/end week combination. Per Henrik's comment, used `floor_date`/`ceiling_date`. I need to `as.Date` the `ceiling_date` because, it rounds the week up to the 20th hour so it returns a class of `POSIXct`.

```
library(lubridate)

dt$start_week <- floor_date(as.Date(dt$date), unit = "week")
dt$end_week <- as.Date(ceiling_date(as.Date(dt$date), unit = "week"))

 ggplot(dt, aes(y = grp)) + geom_segment(aes(x = start_week, xend = end_week, yend = grp)) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = as.Date(date), label = grp), nudge_x = 3, size = 5) + 
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45,hjust=1,vjust=1))+ 
  scale_x_date('Date', date_breaks = '7 days', expand = c(0, 2)) + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set3') + 
  theme(axis.line.y = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Given that you load `lubridate`, you might as well use `floor_date(date, unit = "week")` and `ceiling_date(date, unit = "week")`.

Comment: You can also use `geom_rect` to get a box like shape instead of using `geom_segment`.

Comment: @Henrik, nice I didn't know about those functions. `ceiling_date` returns a `POSIXct`...any idea why? I suppose I could always round it/`as.Date` it, but it seems odd that `floor_date` gives me a `Date` class back but `ceiling_date` doesn't.

Comment: `ggplot(dt, aes(y = grp)) + geom_segment(aes(x = start_week, xend = end_week, yend = grp)) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = as.Date(date), label = grp), nudge_x = 3, size = 5) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5))+
  scale_x_date('Date', date_breaks = '7 days', expand = c(0, 2)) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set3') +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank())`

Comment: this give what I want but still the labels in X are not clearly visible , can someone help me with rotating the labels

Comment: @MikeH. It seems like a bug which have re-appeared. I just commented on a [closed issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/479)

Comment: @Jack see my updates. When you include `theme_bw()` after you change your axis rotation it resets it. I moved it up and also changed the `vjust` to be 1

Comment: @Henrik, thanks. I updated anyway and just used `as.Date` - still more concise this way.

Comment: @MikeH. actually, it is putting the `grp` everywhere and on increasing the size to 6 , those are not even visible, how can I put the `grp` whiich are 01, 02, 03, 04 in this case at the very beginning or at y axis for each of the group only once ?

Comment: @Jack You could remove your `axis.text.y = element_blank()` to not reset the y-axis. Alternatively in your `geom_label` you could just change the `x = ...` to be `x = start_week` if you want it at the beginning or `x = end_week` if you want it at the end.